# Cannot call methods prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, button

I'd like to update the value of a link-button by clicking on the item of a menu.

Html:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-icon="false">
        <li><a href="#">Value A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Value B</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<a href="#" id="selected" data-role="button"></a>
```

jQueryMobile:

```
$('#selected').hide();

$("#menu li a").on('click',function(){
    $('#selected').html($(this).html()).slideDown().button("refresh");
});
```

Text update works fine, but button css is not properly updated.

I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on button prior to initialization;
>   attempted to call method 'refresh'

Which initialization are we talking about ? Page and button are already initialized, aren't they?

---

EDIT:

I also tried this :

```
$(document).on("mobileinit", function() {

    $('#selected').hide();

    $("#menu li a").on('click',function(){
        $('#selected').html($(this).html()).slideDown().button("refresh");
    });

});
```

No error message any more; but no text update :(

Comment: Use `pagebeforeshow’ or `pageshow` instead of `mobileinit`.

Comment: This is better: I get a full width button; but padding is still missing.

Comment: @Yako please check my answer and accept it if it helps...

Answer (score 41):

The issue is sometimes caused by jquery-ui and bootstrap-button plugins conflict.
jquery-ui code should go before bootstrap.js, and that solves the problem.

Comment: Thank you! This was it for me as well. Saved me tons of headache time. :)

Answer (score 3):

### Working example

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/BDmex/

**HTML :**

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-icon="false">
        <li><a href="#">Value A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Value B</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<a href="#" id="selected" data-role="button"></a>
```

**JS :**

```
$('#selected').hide();

$("#menu li a").on('click',function(){
    $('#selected').html('<span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">' + $(this).html() + '</span></span>').slideDown();
});
```

- You were missing data-role="button" inside a button a tag
- Because button was originally created without the text you need to add appropriate inner structure with 2 spans

### Second solution

There's another solution to this problem and it can be found in this **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/uncaught-error-cannot-call-methods-on-prior-to-initialization-attempted-to-call-method-refresh/)** + description and working example.

Comment: The missing data-role was a typo; thanks. I could also use $('#selected .ui-btn-text').html('newText'); But I'm afraid relying on jQueryMobile classes could lead to issues with newer versions. Isn't there a way with Refresh which would be more perennial?

Comment: method button() or button('refresh') has only sence if button is newly created. In your case you already have formed button but without inner span elements. At this point button() will not do anything. This is a reason why I have added span elements. Also you cant just add it to ui-btn-text because it dontr exist if button is created without the text.

Comment: Indeed, the button DOM is created on page load with data-role=button (the button is static). But the css styling is lost when text content is updated. Do you imply that created DOM is deleted when button content is changed?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the HTML structure of your `#selected` link element after jQuery Mobile has initialized it (using a DOM inspector). The actual text is inside a span element with the `ui-btn-text` class. So when you update the HTML of the button with the `.html()` function, you're overwriting the HTML structure that jQuery Mobile created, thereby removing the formatting that jQuery Mobile added.

You can select the `.ui-btn-text` element that is a descendant of your button to update the text without removing the formatting.

Change this:

```
$('#selected').html($(this).html()).slideDown().button("refresh");
```

to this:

```
$('#selected').find(".ui-btn-text").html($(this).html()).slideDown();
```

FYI, here is what an initialized anchor tag button's HTML looks like:

```
<a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-up-c">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner">
        <span class="ui-btn-text">Anchor</span>
    </span>
</a>
```

Source: http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/widgets/buttons/

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and did not manage to find out why it occurs. But knowing that after the initialization a span with class 'ui-btn-text' is placed inside the button I workaround it like this:

```
var button = $("#selected");
var innerTextSpan = button.find(".ui-btn-text");

// not initialized - just change label
if (innerTextSpan.size() == 0) {
    button.text(label);

// already initialized - find innerTextSpan and change its label    
} else {
    innerTextSpan.text(label);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem that I solved by deleting 2 "" final html, so I think it is an imperfection in the html destination page