# How can I reset multiple dropdowns in jquery mobile with custom class at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jquery-mobile

I have this code which resets all the dropdowns when `dropdown1` changes.

```
<select id="name" >
    <option value="">select all</option>
    <option value="1">Text 1</option>
    <option value="2">Text 2</option>
    <option value="3">Text 3</option>
</select>
<select id="name2" class="whatever">
    <option value="">select all</option>
    <option value="1">Text 1</option>
    <option value="2">Text 2</option>
    <option value="3">Text 3</option>
</select>
<select id="name3" class="whatever">
    <option value="">select all</option>
    <option value="1">Text 1</option>
    <option value="2">Text 2</option>
    <option value="3">Text 3</option>
</select>
<select id="name4" class="whatever">
    <option value="">select all</option>
    <option value="1">Text 1</option>
    <option value="2">Text 2</option>
    <option value="3">Text 3</option>
</select>
<select id="name5" class="whatever">
    <option value="">select all</option>
    <option value="1">Text 1</option>
    <option value="2">Text 2</option>
    <option value="3">Text 3</option>
</select>
<select id="name6" class="whatever">
    <option value="">select all</option>
    <option value="1">Text 1</option>
    <option value="2">Text 2</option>
    <option value="3">Text 3</option>
</select>
```

I wanted to select the class and reset all of them at once but the only way to do it is with: `$('select').val('').selectmenu('refresh');`

But what if I want to specify a custom class name like in this case "whatever". How can I do it?

This is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TmJCE/692/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TmJCE/695/)**.

You have just to add it after select :

```
$('#name').change(function(){
     $('select.whatever').val('').selectmenu('refresh');
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just a last question, if you have a chance. If I want to select only .whatever I got the following error:`Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on selectmenu prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'` in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TmJCE/698/

Comment: I'm sorry @SaulOrtega but i can't detect the problem, normally it should work, take a look at [Cannot call methods prior...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597430/cannot-call-methods-prior-to-initialization-attempted-to-call-method-refresh) ).

Comment: No, i can see the error but i don't know how to resolve it.